# How to create a Restore Point using command line in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, system-restore

I have installed Windows 7 64 bit, however it’s behaving erratic. Sometimes network icon goes missing or sometimes USB driver stops working and so on. So far System Restore has saved me every time.

So I am thinking to auto create System Restore every two days at logon.  I can write a BAT script that runs every two days but I am not aware if there’s any way to create a Restore Point using command line.
If there’s any command that can work I would be glad to know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read [Create a system restore](https://hubpages.com/living/How-to-Create-Manual-System-Restore-Point-in-Windows-7-Script)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).

> How to create a Restore Point using command line in Windows 7?

Windows PowerShell has the command you need: `Checkpoint-Computer`. You need to supply a description to it. Like this:

```
Checkpoint-Computer "Some description"
```

You read the full documentation here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Checkpoint-Computer

> So I am thinking to auto create System Restore every two days at logon

Then you asked the wrong question: You want to know how to create a restore point on a schedule, not from a command prompt. (You probably don't even care if don't see a command prompt.)

Use Windows Scheduled Tasks for that. To do this:

1. Right-click on Computer and select "Manage..."
2. Open the following tree path: Computer Management (Local) -> System Tools -> Task Scheduler -> Task Scheduler Library -> Microsoft -> Windows -> SystemRestore
3. Find the task called "SR". (Since there is only that one task, you should have problem finding it.) Double-click on it, or right-click on it and select "Properties".

   [image]
4. In the "Trigger" tab, define a "Daily" trigger for it that recurs every 2 days. Set an starting hour for it. And don't worry, if your computer was not on when this hour comes, the task will start next time your turn on your computer.

Comment: I like to set it to the 'Lock workstation' trigger :-) So everytime I get up I get a backup